# Converting Physical Addresses to long lat coordinates

Tags: excel, geocoding

Hey guys I have been looking around the net and I do not seem to find a viable answer. Here comes: I got a list of 1000ish addresses for which i want to get the coordinates. The dumb thing is that google maps gives me the coodrinates of each point but i gotta go copy/paste 1000 entries to get them, say in excel worksheet. I've seen sites that offer to get me the coords one by one which again is not viable for me. Is there any way to extract the coords of google maps, or any other site that can process large quantities at once?
Thank you

Comment: http://www.findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode/#.Vm6uVuKxXsA
This is it 100% <3 did the job thank you, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write VB Script you can implement the Google API yourself, someone already wrote it for you: [policeanalyst.com/using-the-google-geocoding-api-in-excel](http://policeanalyst.com/using-the-google-geocoding-api-in-excel).

For bulk conversion just do a Google search, there are a couple of sites that claim to do it, this one works: [findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode](http://findlatitudeandlongitude.com/batch-geocode)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your file in text only csv format at 
http://geocoder.ca/?batchupload=1&account=1

Then save the results back to csv, shapefile or even print on a map as pdf or png file.